# CartItems returning 0 during debug c#

Tags: c#, datacontext

I need to create an inventory system and currently my cartitems on my controller page is returning 0. This is the code I have on the controller page.
The process is for a receiving warehouse procedure and the quantity received needs to get updated with the available quantity

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Receiving_Id,Supplier_Name,DateReceived,Receiver_Name,Receiver_Signature,Driver_Name,Driver_Signature,Items")] Receiving receiving)
       
 {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                receiving.DateReceived = DateTime.UtcNow;
               _context.Add(receiving);
                var cartItems = _context.ReceivedItems.Where(cart => cart.Id == receiving.Receiving_Id).ToList();
                foreach (var item in cartItems)
                {
                    receiving.Product = new Product
                    {
                        AvailableQuantity = item.Received_Quantity,
                    };
                    _context.Update(receiving.Product);
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            }
            return View(receiving);
        }
```

Comment: Does `return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index))` get hit or `return View(receiving)` ?

Comment: The debug hits each line but bypasses the foreach statement and hits the await_context  going forward

Comment: Add a break point on the foreach loop and check if `var cartItems` has any value

Answer (score 0):

_context.Add<TYPE_YOU_ARE_ADDING>(receiving.Product)

EG: _context.Add(receiving.Product)

Comment: Did try adding this - it throws a null reference error message

Comment: place a breakpoint on the line "_context.Update(receiving.Product);". Then hover over the receiveing.Product each time in the forloop to see the values.